# How to create the right return function for a nested webservice in moodle

Tags: json, web-services, moodle

I'm trying to build the right response function in my moodle webservice.
I printed the php structure of my json response:

```html
[
   {
      "name":"Quiz",
      "id":"1",
      "theme":"green",
      "quizzes":[
         {
            "type":"single-select-item",
            "question":"Question example 1?",
            "options":[
               "<p>answer1<br><\/p>",
               "<p>answer2<br><\/p>",
               "<p>answer3<br><\/p>",
               "<p>answer4<br><\/p>"
            ],
            "answer":"1"
         },
         {
            "type":"single-select-item",
            "question":"<p>Question example 1?<br><\/p>",
            "options":[
               "<p>answer1<br><\/p>",
               "<p>answer2<br><\/p>",
               "<p>answer3<br><\/p>",
               "<p>answer4<br><\/p>"
            ],
            "answer":"2"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

but I can't write the right return function for moodle webservices .

I have written the return funtion as following

```
        return new external_multiple_structure(
        new external_single_structure(
            array(
                "name"=>  new external_value(PARAM_TEXT, 'quiz name'),
                "id"=>  new external_value(PARAM_TEXT, 'quiz id'),
                "theme"=>  new external_value(PARAM_TEXT, 'quiz theme'),
                "quizzes" => new external_multiple_structure(
                                new external_single_structure(
                                    array(
                                        "type" =>  new external_value(PARAM_TEXT, 'answer type'),
                                        "question" => new external_value(PARAM_TEXT, 'question'),
                                        "options" =>  new external_multiple_structure(
                                                            new external_value(PARAM_TEXT, 'options')
                                                      ),
                                        "answer" => new external_value(PARAM_TEXT, 'right answer')
                                    )
                                )

                            )


            )
        )
    );
```

but I still receive the following exception. What's wrong in my return function?

{"exception":"invalid_response_exception","errorcode":"invalidresponse","message":"Invalid response value detected"}

any suggestion?
thank you

Comment: what exception is raised?

Comment: {"exception":"invalid_response_exception","errorcode":"invalidresponse","message":"Invalid response value detected"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the problem!!
The return function is correct but I receive exception because some text inside the structure contains HTML tags like  and escape characters that break the return function composition.
Finally I used this PARAM_RAW instead of PARAM_TEXT and it works like a charm!

Comment: thanks so much - your fix worked for me too. I was getting the course summary field and it has html in it. I changed my parameter type to PARAM_RAW and it worked. Yay!!!